# To what extent can we call a Geometric Distribution a Geometric Density

Tags: distributions, discrete-data

In some papers, for example in ["The Geometric Density with Unknown Location Parameter"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2239262) by Klotz, a Geometric Distribution is called a Geometric Density.

For me, this claim looks erroneous, however Klotz is a serious statistician and a professor in the field.

My question is, to what extend is it legitimate to call a Geometric Distribution a Geometric Density?

Comment: This question is a repost of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/536/when-a-serious-statistician-calls-a-geometric-distribution-a-geometric-density-t (see comments there). @Hibernating is the original question-asker

Comment: I am guessing it is a typo or an oversight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Heuristic answer:** Without much mathematic you could say that a continuous variable has a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, and a discrete random variable has a density with respect to the counting measure.

**Developped answer:** The concept of density is much wider than you may think. A density of a probability measure $P$ can be defined with respect to a measure $\lambda$ that dominates $P$ by the Radon Nikodym Theorem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). Here density should be understood as a density with respect to the counting measure defined on the mentionned countable set. I agree that it is not extremely rigorous not to mention the reference when talking about a density (but who mention density  wrt lesbesgue measure?), but it pose no problem while reading the paper in question so ....

---

Additional Annex Notes
 I have seen a certain number of machine learning notes (I won't do delation) where  the reference measure is not the counting measure and we see things such as $P(X=x|Y=y)$ with X being a continuous variable (with a density wrt Lebesgues) (to apply Bayes principle and derive the Bayes rule). I guess people want to be pedagogic and do not want to bother students with technical details ;) My conclusion would be that even great mathematician can commit abuse of wording or of notation (it is not the case in the paper you mention because the authors of a paper in AoP may have mathematical background), it is not a problem as along as it is understood by everyone...

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow much of what you wrote as I am not a trained mathematician. Are you saying that all 'discrete distributions' are in some sense densities under a very general definition?

Comment: Without much mathematic you could say that a continuous variable has a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, and a discrete random variable has a density with respect to the counting measure.